# Why does Monica's apartment look different in s01e10?

Tags: friends

I may have missed the explanation of this, but Monica's apartment looks very different from every other episode of *Friends* in episode 10 of the first season. Why is that?

Comment: Could you provide some sort of visual to better illustrate what you're talking about?

Comment: Do you mean the fact that it was a New Year's Eve episode and there were a lot of seasonal decorations around? Or do you mean that the entire set is somehow different?

Answer (score 4):

The reason the apartment looks different is it's the build up to the gang's New Years Eve party and decorations are up (possibly from Christmas?). Apart from the obvious monkey...

[image: image of the kitchen]

- Red and silver tinsel around the apartment door (just off screen on the left)
- Silver star hanging from the ceiling behind the apartment door (just off screen on the left)
- Gold tinsel in the kitchen work surface
- Red Christmas lights in the kitchen
- More silver stars hanging in the kitchen
- Decorations on all of the wooden beams in the kitchen
- Some kind of tree with decorations between the kitchen and the living area

[image: the rest of the apartment]

- Fake snow on all of the bay windows
- Christmas lights out on the balcony (it's worth noting these are missing from the above screenshot but appear in the scene before the credits and later on... 10/10 for set management)
- Big tree (that gets decorated later in the episode) near the bay window
- Wreath hanging from the bay window

Oh, and lots more people than usual (later in the episode, during the party).